# Maven proxy authentication

Tags: maven

I have recently joined a new team. They have given me a settings.xml file.

```
<proxies>
<proxy>
  <id>example-proxy</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>proxy.example.com</host>
  <port>8080</port>
  <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>somepassword</password>
</proxy>
```

When I run mvn clean install to pull the jars, I am getting this error

`Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy.example.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

What is missing? Should I add the details in the hosts file? I have never used a proxy before, so please tell me what I should ask the team.

Comment: Where have you placed that settings.xml?

Comment: $HOME/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: And where is your maven installation??

Comment: U should replace that file with your system's maven installation something like .../apache-maven/conf/settings.xml

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan do not replace the system configuration. Better change the `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` which is local and not related to the maven installation.

Comment: He is in a workspace system so better to update the conf directly to his installation since it's his local development pc and maven would be used in multiple projects. I do the same and it works. But maybe I'm wrong.